# PHP if image exceeds 1000px using getimagesize()

Tags: php, jquery-validate, getimagesize

I'm using the remote method used in [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

I'm referring to a PHP file shown below:

```
<?php

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($right_form_url);
$size = getimagesize($title);
$size[3] = $width;

if ($width > 1000) {
   $output = false;
} else {
   $output = true;
}
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

It never returns anything no matter how I put the `$output` variables. I've tried other PHP files that I know work in validation, so I think it has something to do with my IF statement, although I'm fairly certain the width is being declared correctly.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Are you doing any kind of debugging? For example, what does `$right_form_url` contain?

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is that a typo or you assign empty `$width` variable to `$size[3]`?

Comment: @arma: Yeah, switched them back. Still doesn't work. @wescrow: Fixed. @Pekka: `Right_form_url` is the id of the input that the validation is being applied to. It's always passed them that way when I've used the remote method in the past.

Comment: Where is $width coming from? Right now it appears that you're trying to overwrite the $size[3] element with an undefined width. I would think you'd want $width=$size[0] in there to define the width.

Comment: Also, why are you mysql_real_escape_string()ing a passed variable? It doesn't appear that you're going to be sending this title into a query.

Comment: @BenD That did it. I'm not sure how I missed that. Usually I'm comparing to my database. I must've just overlooked and thought it was what allowed the input to pass over from the form in validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is invalid. You are setting `$size[3] = $width;` which sould be `$width = $size[0];`
Two mistakes:
1. You were setting `$size[3]` to `$width`, but should set `$width` to `$size[3]`
2. `$size[3]` containts string valu t use with html image tag(height="yyy" width="xxx"), `$size[0]` conatins numeric value of width

Comment: Try `$output = array("result" => true)` and `$output = array("result" => false)` instead. And if still not working make php script with only `json_endode(true)` or `json_encode(array("result" => true))` maybe that's what not working.

Comment: If you look at the comments from original post, it was because of the `mysql_escape_string` function. Other than that, the `$size[0]` was your answer, so I'll select yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know your problem, here, the json_enconde function only supports data with UTF-8 encoding, then if your site uses another encoding, the function will return NULL, so try this:

```
<?php

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($right_form_url);
$size = getimagesize($title);
$size[3] = $width;

$output = true;    
if ($width > 1000) {
   $output = false;
}
echo json_encode(base64_encode($output));

?>
```